# I still remember it as if it ... yesterday

Tags: differences

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tenses after “as if”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/55279/tenses-after-as-if)

What is the difference of the following sentences?

- I still remember it as if it was yesterday.
- I still remember it as if it were yesterday.
- I still remember it as if it had been yesterday.
- I still remember it as if it happened yesterday.
- I still remember it as if it had happened yesterday.

Which one would you rather use when you look back at your life? (So you look back at events that might be years ago.)

Comment: It might depend on exactly *which part* of your life you're looking back on, since obviously your entire past life does in fact ***include*** whatever happened yesterday.

Comment: 3 and 5 use the pluperfect, and would be better attached to "I still remembered it"

Answer (score 2):

The first two are alternative ways of saying the same thing, with the second being a little more formal. The third and the fifth have an odd sequence of tenses, because *had* in the *if* clause requires the past tense in the main clause, with a consequent change of *yesterday* to *the day before*. *Happened* tends to refer to a single event, whereas the verb *be* would be appropriate if you were looking back at an extended period of your life.