# As if and as though

Tags: grammar, word-usage, phrase-usage, conditionals, rules

A few weeks ago one of my friends looked at my daughter and said "She looks as if she is not your daughter" is it correct to use present tense in a situation like that? The thing is that she knew that she was mine. Does the fact that she knew she was my daughter make this situation unreal? would it be better if she had said "she looks as if she were not your daughter"? thank you so munch in advance.

Comment: It's rare to use subjunctive in spoken English, and simple present is far more common. I'm sure there have been similar questions asked here that may be useful.

Comment: This says that in common everyday English the present tense is used after "as if" if it's something the speaker believes or that appears to be true. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/55279/tenses-after-as-if linking to http://alt-usage-english.org/excerpts/fxsubjun.html (I'm not sure if it counts as a duplicate)

Comment: Such a comment might be seen as very rude, especially if said to the father.