# I am trying to find out differences between between a bunch of "would" conditionals

Tags: grammaticality, differences, conditionals, modal-verbs

I am confused about how to correctly use *if* with *would (+have)* or 
*could (+have)* while talking about past activities in conditionals.

Please check out these sentences and help me to figure out their differences:

1. Even if I **had tried**, I would **not have** known.
2. Even if I **had tried**, I would **have not** known.
3. Even if I **would have tried**, I would **not have** known.
4. Even if I **would try**, I would **not have** known.
5. Even if I **try**, I would **not** know.
6. Even if I **would try**, I **had not** known.

Are those all grammatical and meaningful? If not, which ones aren’t?
What does each one mean and when should I use it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["If I would have lost you" vs "If I had lost you".](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/62482/if-i-would-have-lost-you-vs-if-i-had-lost-you) See also [Is 'had have + past participle' a correct grammatical form?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/290111/is-had-have-past-participle-a-correct-grammatical-form) and [“If I knew you're coming I wouldn't have come”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/47124/if-i-knew-youre-coming-i-wouldnt-have-come?noredirect=1&lq=1), among others.

Comment: ...in practice most people use the contracted version of #3 - *Even if **I'd** [have] tried, I would not have known*. But there's disagreement over whether that ***'d*** is actually a reduced version of ***had*** (my gut feel) or ***would*** (what prescriptive grammarians think). Obviously that issue can be sidestepped by discarding the word ***have***, but not everyone does that.